# Location field not present in POST response headers

Tags: python, post, python-requests, response-headers

I am trying to log in to a webpage using the Python requests library. I am sending a POST request to the link and getting a response back, but I am missing the 'Location' item in the response headers. I am using the following code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://aab.powerapp.nl/login'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
token = soup.find('input', {'name': '_token'}).get('value')
headers['Cookie'] = '; '.join([x.name + '=' + x.value for x in response.cookies])
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
payload = {
        '_token': token,
        'emailaddress': '', 
        'password': ''
}
response = requests.post(url + '/validate', files=payload, headers=headers)
```

The requests headers as shown in Chrome are the following:

```
POST /login/validate HTTP/1.1
Host: aab.powerapp.nl
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Origin: https://aab.powerapp.nl
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://aab.powerapp.nl/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InkyK1pWbzRcL3dmbVRPeVwvNW52UjFyUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJWazZXRGFDb0tWcGQ1WjhleHdSRzZYU202WXN3bG4wbG9YQnZZcUNYTndDcXJETDl2MGIrY0dnUVlOcUhoTmZKIiwibWFjIjoiZmNmNzlmMjc5YWRiMmMyNjk0MmI1YjE5ZTE2OTNmZGU5YTRlNDA0MDg3ZGE4NTI1ZTc3NTBkZjg0MjFjOTQzNSJ9; pa_session_aabp=eyJpdiI6IjlidWIxdlVybFl0UjJHOXorcnFmT2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM0JZXC9NNHJOWlFIVjBhQ2xxelN2ZENrSVBuTkpibzJybUhkSHRUeGpSTTRITnFyK2E1M3ExM2VjWjNnNG4rbXMiLCJtYWMiOiJmN2NjZGRkNjc2YTJkZjBjNGVkZDczODNlZDI1YTk5YTllODk1YmFiMDc4Mzc5MWM2ZDZmMThiZjNmMzU0MmU5In0%3D
```

I am only receiving the following headers:

```
{'Date': 'Sat, 29 Jun 2019 15:40:15 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Set-Cookie': 'pa_session_aabp=eyJpdiI6ImFwS21QNVpMRGh1ZHJ0ZW1vbCtia1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRHZHa1wvZlNKMnkzZVEzTCthQVZ1eGdjSmRVbEZVSVJ2RHN5ZXZwNEV6NmRkZVZnTVhTMVlGUWxES1dYUmdvQlgiLCJtYWMiOiIyNWRhYTRkNzUyZTdiYmI4ODYwMDBkMmVjMDRmNzliYzZmZDAzNzg4N2NiMTdkMWI3Y2YyZjQyOGI0MDFiZWJlIn0%3D; path=/; domain=aab.powerapp.nl; secure; httponly', 'Location': 'https://aab.powerapp.nl/login', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Language': 'nl'}
```

I have tried setting the allow_redirects argument to both `True` and `False` but I am still unable to get the `Location` item back in the response headers. Next to that, I have tried setting several different requests headers, including the `Cookie`, `Referer`, and `User-Agent`. In addition to the `emailaddress` and `password` that are sent in the requests as form data, a third field, `_token`, is being sent. I am unsure whether or not that could be the cause of the problem as I am also not sure how the value of the token is decided.

EDIT:
I found out that the token that is also sent as a form data can be extracted from the html of the login page. I have made some changes to my script to reflect this knowledge. Unfortunately, this does not seem to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by using a requests `session` combined with using the data argument instead of the files argument. Code is below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()
url = 'https://aab.powerapp.nl/login'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
token = soup.find('input', {'name': '_token'}).get('value')
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
payload = {
        '_token': token,
        'emailaddress': '', 
        'password': ''
}
response = session.post(url + '/validate', data=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to send your credentials once per session, at the start, and after you successfully pass that process you get that token string that is valid for some time defined on server side. Any other call to api after authorization needs that token to be sent as a header.

Comment: I am only sending my credentials once. I have also just tried getting the token from manually logging in and adding that to the payload dictionary, but even then I am still not getting the `Location` header.

Comment: Payload represents the data, token probably should be in [headers](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers). Do you have any api documentation for this server or you're just trying to automate a process? And why this `validate` url, where you've got it?

Comment: I think that the token should be in the payload since it is sent as form data just like the email and password. I unfortunately do not have any api documentation for the server, as you assumed correctly I am trying to automate a process. 

I am not sure what you exactly mean in your second question, but the validate url is the url that the login requests is sent to. I simply see that a post request is sent to that url in the chrome devtools, which returns a 302 code (see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/sGmD75r.png)).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with this, it will probably come to trying. Also dunno is it possible to fool that ServiceWorker that sent the 302.

Comment: I found out where I could get the token that is sent in the POST with the email and password. I have made some changes to my code (see OP), do you have any other ideas as to what the cause of the problem might be?